# why does bootstrap glyphicon not displaying as anticipated

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i tried using the bootstrap glyphicon for login and user, what i got was actually a square box instead of the anticipated image icon. Could this be that the file is broken? or the glypicon just doesn't work?

```
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
```

Before you guys think i did a wrong reference, The glyphicon for envelope did worked fine. But the ones i actually needed just didn't work.

Comment: it is better use <i> tag instead of using <span>. And post your code sample HTML/CSS

Comment: Tried updating bootstrap files?? ,, if you are referencing them locally? also check if your bootstrap.css has a definition for .glyphicon-user

Comment: yea i did locally and the version am using is the latest i guess

Comment: First try bootstrap cdn, if it solve your problem then something is wrong with your bootstrap files path that you stored locally.